# Issue with Version Conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Install Referance 3.1.2 in .NetCore 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.2

I m working with N-tier architecture with .netcore 2.2

see how my project structure:

**MainProject Version**: how I m create the project(ASP.NET Core Web Application->Next->create->Empty(select the DropDown ASP.NET Core 2.2)

[image]

**business logic** project Version: how I m create the project(class library .net core)

[image]

**data access** project Version: how I m create the project(class library .net core)

[image]

**model** project Version: how I m create the project(class library .net core)

[image]

Error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.2 directly to the project  to resolve this issue. 
 projectname-> projectname.BusinessLogic -> projectname.DataAccess -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.2) 
 projectname-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).   projectname
```

when I click on an error then this file display:

projectname.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DMEBase.BusinessLogic\DMEBase.BusinessLogic.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DMEBase.Model\DMEBase.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Only 1 error is generated in my project

how to solve this issue? help

NuGet Packages ScreenShot:

[image]

**Write Click On Solution then I m going to Managenugetpackages->Consolidate->No Packages Found**:
[image]

Comment: I check all projects have own SDK Microsoft.NETCore.App(2.2.0)

Comment: Paste a screenshot of solution nuget packages

Comment: @ Yahya Hussein I m still facing this issue can u tell me which framework is remaining in my project does not have NuGet folder

Comment: right click on your solution (not project) then choose "manage nuget packages for solution" then go to Consolidate tab

Comment: @YahyaHussein still I m trying to solve the problem?

Comment: did you do what I told you in my previous comment? the screenshot you pasted is not what I need, please follow the steps in previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209068/discussion-between-rahul-and-yahya-hussein).

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade entity framework core version as compatible core framework.
[image]

Comment: I edit my question to see my main project package and which framework is remaining in my project?